How do I dynamically set object attributes using a lists inside a dataclass object?
Currently I have this code that looks really repetitive in some areas:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Locator:
    locator_attr: str
    transform: str = field(init=False)
    position: tuple = field(init=False)
    point_on_curve: str = field(init=False)
    normal_attr: str = field(init=False)
    normal: tuple = field(init=False)
    normalizedNormal_attr: str = field(init=False)
    normalizedNormal: tuple = field(init=False)
    tangent_attr: str = field(init=False)
    tangent: tuple = field(init=False)
    normalizedTangent_attr: str = field(init=False)
    normalizedTangent: tuple = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.transform = cmds.listConnections(f"{self.locator_attr}.locatorTransform")[0]
        self.position = cmds.xform(self.transform, q=True, t=True, ws=True)
        self.point_on_curve = cmds.listConnections(f"{self.locator_attr}.pointOnCurve")[0]
        self.normal_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.normal"
        self.normal = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.normal")[0]
        self.normalizedNormal_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedNormal"
        self.normalizedNormal = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedNormal")[0]
        self.tangent_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.tangent"
        self.tangent = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.tangent")[0]
        self.normalizedTangent_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedTangent"
        self.normalizedTangent = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedTangent")[0]

Same in the section
    normal_attr: str = field(init=False)
    normal: tuple = field(init=False)
    normalizedNormal_attr: str = field(init=False)
    normalizedNormal: tuple = field(init=False)
    tangent_attr: str = field(init=False)
    tangent: tuple = field(init=False)
    normalizedTangent_attr: str = field(init=False)
    normalizedTangent: tuple = field(init=False)

And
        self.normal_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.normal"
        self.normal = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.normal")[0]
        self.normalizedNormal_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedNormal"
        self.normalizedNormal = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedNormal")[
            0
        ]
        self.tangent_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.tangent"
        self.tangent = cmds.getAttr(f"{self.point_on_curve}.tangent")[0]
        self.normalizedTangent_attr = f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedTangent"
        self.normalizedTangent = cmds.getAttr(
            f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedTangent"
        )[0]

The terms ['normal','normalizedNormal','tangent','normalizedTangent'] are repeated and in case I wanted to add a new attribute I would need to modify a lot of lines.
I tried creating a list inside the class, so I could add an attribute only by adding it to the list:
_node_attrs:list = field(default_factory=['normal','normalizedNormal','tangent','normalizedTangent'])
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Locator:
    locator_attr: str
    transform: str = field(init=False)
    position: tuple = field(init=False)
    point_on_curve: str = field(init=False)
    _node_attrs:list = ['normal','normalizedNormal','tangent','normalizedTangent']
    for _attrname in _node_attrs:
        globals()[f'{_attrname}_attr']: str = field(init=False)
        globals()[f'{_attrname}']: tuple = field(init=False)
    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.transform = cmds.listConnections(f"{self.locator_attr}.locatorTransform")[0]
        self.position = cmds.xform(self.transform, q=True, t=True, ws=True)
        self.point_on_curve = cmds.listConnections(f"{self.locator_attr}.pointOnCurve")[
            0
        ]

If the list is a Field I got the error:
# Error: 'Field' object is not iterable
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 3, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 10, in Locator
# TypeError: 'Field' object is not iterable #

but in case I change to a simple list I got
# Error: mutable default <class 'list'> for field _node_attrs is not allowed: use default_factory
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 3, in <module>
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\dataclasses.py", line 1010, in dataclass
#     return wrap(_cls)
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\dataclasses.py", line 1002, in wrap
#     return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash, frozen)
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\dataclasses.py", line 850, in _process_class
#     for name, type in cls_annotations.items()]
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\dataclasses.py", line 850, in <listcomp>
#     for name, type in cls_annotations.items()]
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\dataclasses.py", line 733, in _get_field
#     raise ValueError(f'mutable default {type(f.default)} for field '
# ValueError: mutable default <class 'list'> for field _node_attrs is not allowed: use default_factory # 

Whats the cleanest way to do it using dataclass?

default_factory has to be a callable that takes no arguments and returns the default value, that could explain one of your errors, since a list is not callable. It would be easier to diagnose the errors if you posted the full trace back and not just the error message.

You could fix the default_factory by using a lambda function _node_attrs: list = field(default_factory=lambda: ['normal', ...]), but the rest of the code is imho not valid (loop directly after the _node_attrs).

Here's a bit of a frame challenge... what if you eliminate the duplication with properties — or, to compute them only once, as in your code, cached properties?
from functools import cached_property


class Locator:
    def __init__(self, locator_attr: str):
        self.locator_attr = locator_attr
    
    @cached_property
    def transform() -> str:
       return cmds.listConnections(f"{self.locator_attr}.locatorTransform")[0]
    
    @cached_property
    def position() -> tuple:
       return cmds.xform(self.transform, q=True, t=True, ws=True)
    
    @cached_property
    def point_on_curve() -> str:
       return cmds.listConnections(f"{self.locator_attr}.pointOnCurve")[0]
    
    @cached_property
    def normal() -> tuple:
       return cmds.getAttr(self.normal_attr)[0]
    
    @cached_property
    def normalizedNormal_attr() -> str:
       return f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedNormal"
    
    @cached_property
    def normalizedNormal() -> tuple:
       return cmds.getAttr(self.normalizedNormal_attr)[0]
    
    @cached_property
    def tangent_attr() -> str:
       return f"{self.point_on_curve}.tangent"
    
    @cached_property
    def tangent() -> tuple:
       return cmds.getAttr(self.tangent_attr)[0]
    
    @cached_property
    def normalizedTangent_attr() -> str:
       return f"{self.point_on_curve}.normalizedTangent"
    
    @cached_property
    def normalizedTangent() -> tuple:
       return cmds.getAttr(self.normalizedTangent_attr)[0]

This way you can still access, for instance, my_locator.position, you keep your type annotations, you don't need any hacks, and it's defined all in once place.
(This is still perfectly compatible with dataclass, by the way; I only removed it here because it's not doing much heavy lifting with locator_attr as the only attribute.)
Note that with this setup, the attributes are "lazy"; they're not computed until requested. Also, as a general rule, if you're going to go down the route of type hints, you might as well make them specific; tuple could be anything, compared to say, tuple[int, int, int] or the like.
The only other thing I changed was I also removed the duplicated definitions of the attribute strings.

The problematic part appears to be this:
@dataclass
class Locator:
    # snip
    _node_attrs:list = field(default_factory=['normal','normalizedNormal','tangent','normalizedTangent'])
    for _attrname in _node_attrs:
        globals()[f'{_attrname}_attr']: str = field(init=False)
        globals()[f'{_attrname}']: tuple = field(init=False)

There are two things that are going wrong here that I can see:

Since you’re iterating over _node_attrs outside of a method, you’re operating on the values before the dataclass decorator has a chance to process the class. As a result, instead of getting the default value for _node_attrs, you’re getting the raw field object that wraps it, but not in a way that lets you directly interact with the value by iterating over it.
You’re assigning the names generated to globals() instead of locals(), which won’t affect the class scope, and so dataclass won’t see those attributes. Also, the type annotations are not going to be saved when you’re assigning to a dict entry unless you explicitly assign the annotation in __annotations__.

This might work:
@dataclass
class Locator:
    # snip
    __annotations__ = {}
    _node_attrs = ['normal','normalizedNormal','tangent','normalizedTangent']
    for _attrname in _node_attrs:
        locals()[f'{_attrname}_attr'] = field(init=False)
        locals()[_attrname] = field(init=False)
        __annotations__[f'{_attrname}_attr'] = str 
        __annotations__[_attrname] = tuple
    # remove variables you don't want in the class scope
    del _attrname
    del _node_attrs

